# Why won't this function work in an Object-Oriented style of javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access the function as a method of the person object why won't it access the method and do what the function is supposed to do?

```
function Person(name, age, location) {
this.name= name;
this.age = age;
this.location = location;
this.test = function() {
    alert("TEST");
};

}   
var Matt = new Person("Matthew", "21", "South Africa");
Matt.test;
```

Comment: Ok I relaized at the very last line you have to add Matt.test() then it will access it.. not sure why it won't do it by reference though..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the method with parenthesis:

```
Matt.test();
```

This will execute the function. Otherwise what you're getting with `Matt.test` is the function itself, which can be passed into another function, stored inside a variable, etc. Then you could execute this function at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

Well since its a function use:

```
Matt.test();
```